# How can I save matplotlib images that were generated using putty?

Tags: python, graph, save, putty

I am attempting to generate a graph using python code I run on a remote server through putty.

I tried using using:

```
   plt.scatter(df['Allele Frequency'], df['Effect Size'], marker='.')

   plt.xlabel('Frequency at Causative Site')
   plt.ylabel('Effect Size')

   plt.savefig('~/test3/scatter01.png')
```

This saves graphs when I use the code on my computer, but it does not work through putty for some reason.

Comment: چاکر محسن، عزیز چه خطایی میده؟

Comment: I don't speak farsi

Comment: This have nothing to do with PuTTY. Show us how you run your python code.

Comment: would you provide us with more details?

Comment: I did an edit to for more detials

Comment: After submitted on PuTTY, the code works and gives me details about the df datatable I ask for (with df.info), but it does not save the graph like I ask it to

Comment: So you get no error? After the script finishes, what do you get if you use `ls ~/test3/scatter01.png`? or `ls ~/test3`?